# on C part of C++ project (VS10)

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

I have a C++ VS2010 project. I want it to be pure C, so I will have a pure C library and a C++ file that will call that library.

- Is it possible? Will I have be able to pass data from the C part to C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  See [how to mix c and c++](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html).

Of course, you could (probably) just compile the c code with a c++ compiler and save yourself a headache.

If you want to link object files compiled by a c compiler, you'll need to use `extern "C" { }` to declare the functions, so that they aren't [name mangled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) by the C++ compiler.

It really depends on how you want to build your project.  If you're more specific, you'll get better answers.

Comment: and can I declare includes like  #include “cv.h”
#include “highgui.h” inside extern "C" { }?

Comment: You can, but note that it may be problematic with nested includes.  See this thread: http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/external_linkage.html